# installed new module, orchard Runtime error

Tags: runtime, orchardcms

I just installed a new Module in Orchard to update the email Module because my email wasn't working. However as soon as I did this now when I try to enter the Admin portion of the site I get a Runtime error. Does anyone know why this happened or what I can do to go back to the previous point? I can't do anything to the site now with the Admin mode not working.

**Invalid object name 'Orchard_Email_SmtpSettingsPartRecord'.
Statement(s) could not be prepared.**

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Orchard_Email_SmtpSettingsPartRecord'.
Statement(s) could not be prepared.

**Source Error:**

> The source code that generated this unhandled exception can only be
>   shown when compiled in debug mode. To enable this, please follow one
>   of the below steps, then request the URL:
>
> 1. Add a "Debug=true" directive at the top of the file that generated the error. Example:
>
> or:
>
> 2) Add the following section to the configuration file of your
>   application:
>
> Note that this second technique will cause all files within a given
>   application to be compiled in debug mode. The first technique will
>   cause only that particular file to be compiled in debug mode.
>
> Important: Running applications in debug mode does incur a
>   memory/performance overhead. You should make sure that an application
>   has debugging disabled before deploying into production scenario.

**Stack Trace:**

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name
>   'Orchard_Email_SmtpSettingsPartRecord'. Statement(s) could not be
>   prepared.]    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +1767866    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +5352418    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1691
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +365
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds) +1406
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) +177
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) +53
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +134
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +41
>
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +10
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.SqlAzure.<>c__DisplayClassc`1.b__a()
>   in :0
>   Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Func`1
>   func) in :0
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.SqlAzure.<>c__DisplayClassc`1.b__9()
>   in :0
>   Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0()
>   in :0
>   Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Func`1
>   func) in :0
>   Microsoft.Practices.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Action
>   action) in :0
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.WindowsAzure.TransientFaultHandling.SqlAzure.ReliableSqlConnection.ExecuteCommand(IDbCommand
>   command, RetryPolicy retryPolicy, CommandBehavior behavior) in :0
>   NHibernate.SqlAzure.ReliableSqlCommand.ExecuteReader() in
>   c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\99f31db0d548c7b7\NHibernate.SqlAzure\ReliableSqlCommand.cs:85
>   NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd) in
>   c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\AbstractBatcher.cs:229 
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean
>   autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection,
>   ISessionImplementor session) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:1224
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session,
>   QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in
>   c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:419
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(ISessionImplementor
>   session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in
>   c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:251
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.LoadEntity(ISessionImplementor session,
>   Object id, IType identifierType, Object optionalObject, String
>   optionalEntityName, Object optionalIdentifier, IEntityPersister
>   persister) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:1279
>
> [GenericADOException: could not load an entity:
>   [Orchard.Email.Models.SmtpSettingsPartRecord#1][SQL: SELECT
>   smtpsettin0_.Id as Id61_0_, smtpsettin0_.Address as Address61_0_,
>   smtpsettin0_.Host as Host61_0_, smtpsettin0_.Port as Port61_0_,
>   smtpsettin0_.EnableSsl as EnableSsl61_0_,
>   smtpsettin0_.RequireCredentials as RequireC6_61_0_,
>   smtpsettin0_.UserName as UserName61_0_, smtpsettin0_.Password as
>   Password61_0_ FROM Orchard_Email_SmtpSettingsPartRecord smtpsettin0_
>   WHERE smtpsettin0_.Id=?]]
>   NHibernate.Loader.Loader.LoadEntity(ISessionImplementor session,
>   Object id, IType identifierType, Object optionalObject, String
>   optionalEntityName, Object optionalIdentifier, IEntityPersister
>   persister) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:1287
>   NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader.Load(ISessionImplementor
>   session, Object id, Object optionalObject, Object optionalId) in
>   c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Entity\AbstractEntityLoader.cs:44
>   NHibernate.Loader.Entity.AbstractEntityLoader.Load(Object id, Object
>   optionalObject, ISessionImplementor session) in
>   c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Entity\AbstractEntityLoader.cs:39
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Load(Object id,
>   Object optionalObject, LockMode lockMode, ISessionImplementor session)
>   in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Persister\Entity\AbstractEntityPersister.cs:3483
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.LoadFromDatasource(LoadEvent
>   event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType
>   options) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultLoadEventListener.cs:348
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.DoLoad(LoadEvent
>   event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType
>   options) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultLoadEventListener.cs:329
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.Load(LoadEvent
>   event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType
>   options) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultLoadEventListener.cs:110
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultLoadEventListener.ProxyOrLoad(LoadEvent
>   event, IEntityPersister persister, EntityKey keyToLoad, LoadType
>   options) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Event\Default\DefaultLoadEventListener.cs:166
>   Orchard.Data.Providers.OrchardLoadEventListener.OnLoad(LoadEvent
>   event, LoadType loadType) in
>   c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Providers\AbstractDataServicesProvider.cs:156
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireLoad(LoadEvent event, LoadType
>   loadType) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:2529
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get(String entityName, Object id) in
>   c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:1366
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get(Type entityClass, Object id) in
>   c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:1303
>   NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Get(Object id) in
>   c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My
>   Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:1287
>   Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Get(Int32 id) in
>   c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:87
>
>   Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Orchard.Data.IRepository.Get(Int32 id) in
>   c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:56
>   Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.StorageFilter`1.GetRecordCore(ContentItemVersionRecord
>   versionRecord) in
>   c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Handlers\StorageFilter.cs:30 
>   Orchard.ContentManagement.Handlers.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Loading>b__0(TRecord
>   prior) in
>   c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Handlers\StorageFilter.cs:54 
>   Orchard.ContentManagement.Utilities.LazyField`1.GetValue() in
>   c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\Utilities\LazyField.cs:24
>   Orchard.Email.Models.SmtpSettingsPart.IsValid() +15
>   Orchard.Email.Services.d__1.MoveNext() +101
>   System.Linq.d__14`2.MoveNext() +293
>
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +381
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
>   Orchard.UI.Admin.Notification.NotificationManager.GetNotifications()
>   in
>   c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\UI\Admin\Notification\NotificationManager.cs:20
>   Orchard.UI.Admin.Notification.AdminNotificationFilter.OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext
>   filterContext) in
>   c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\UI\Admin\Notification\NotificationFilter.cs:35 
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +163
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +420
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +52
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
>   +173    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +41
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +31    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) in c:\Orchard\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:159
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9515512    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Can you please elaborate on 'a Runtime error'? It's not really helpful.

Comment: I'm actually really new at this and I'm trying to figure out where to find the actual log of what went wrong. Do you know where orchard keeps this?

Comment: actually I think I got it. Adding this to the main part

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I just installed a new Module in Orchard to update the email Module because my email wasn't working"? What new module? Where did you get it? What version is it, and what version of Orchard do you have? How is your email not working?

Comment: The email would give me an error message if i filled out a custom form saying the email could not be sent. So I tried to redownload 
Email Messaging - Version: 1.6
I was using 
Contact Form - Version: 0.9.4
 Along with it.  I was running version 1.8 of orchard. Now the site wont even give me the dashboard so I don't know how to check anything else